ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : use System.Json.Text ModelBinding error message is not correct
I post the data by [FromBody], can not get the correct error message, but use [FromForm] can.
I have a model like this
public class ReservationReplyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateOnly DueDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateOnly CommitDate { get; set; }
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
}

And this is my action method:
[HttpPost("{reservation_no}/Reply")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReplyAsync(string reservation_no, [FromBody] ReservationReplyViewModel model)
{
    // do something
}

Then I post the data with
{
  "DueDate": null,
  "CommitDate": null,
  "Comment": null
}

I get an error like

The model field is required

but I want to get the error message like

"The DueDate field is required." and "The CommitDate field is required."

I don't know how to handle with errors after Json deserialization.
Please help.

remove [Required] attribute from model and it will work perfectly.

but i want it required, I want exactly which fields are required

According to the model this is working well for the fromdbody, do you mean you want the fromform still working for required? Which request you sent to the fromform?

I send the all fields null from FormData. And I can get the error message "The DueDate field is required." and "The CommitDate field is required.

This is because when you use [FromBody], the JSON deserialization process happens before model validation which caused the issue, I suggest you could change the codes to this and test [FromBody] ReservationReplyViewModel model.

But I don't know how to handle errors during JSON deserialization and clearly indicate which field the problem occurs

[Required] attribute has an input parameter ErrorMessage that you can use to specify the exact error message, like this:
[Required(ErrorMessage = "DueDate is required.")]
public DateOnly DueDate { get; set; }

Refference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-8.0#examples

I know this, this works correctly when I use [FromForm]. But when I use [FromBody], I don’t get to this part because of the Json deserialization problem.

Please update your question with the correct model definition. Your question is misleading.

I suggest you could use the NewtonsoftJson package instead of the System.Text.Json.
You could install it by using below command
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 8.0.5

Then you modify the public async Task<IActionResult> ReplyAsync(string reservation_no, [FromBody] ReservationReplyViewModel model)
to
    [HttpPost("{reservation_no}/Reply")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReplyAsync(string reservation_no, [FromBody] ReservationReplyViewModel? model)
    {
        // do something
        return Ok();
    }

Result:


Can I custom the error message like "The DueDate field is required".

Yes, we could write custom validation method for this kind of situation.
